# How to display input like "0.052" in calculator display?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, calculator, addeventlistener

I'm building calculator from the odin project. I have problem with addEventListener for buttons elements.
I have to handle situation when user input something like 0.53. I don't know what condition i have to use in if statement for that to work.
Here is a link to my code:
[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/velizarvesovic/pen/qBLrEoQ)

I tried this code first but it didn't work.

```
buttons.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    displayValue = e.target.innerText;
    if (display.innerText.charAt(0) == 0 && display.innerText.charAt(1) == 0) {
      display.innerText = +[display.innerText].shift().toString();
      // display.innerText = display.innerText.replace(/^0+/, "");
    } else if (
      display.innerText.charAt(0) == 0 &&
      display.innerText.charAt(1) >= 1
    ) {
      display.innerText = +[display.innerText].shift().toString();
    }
    display.innerText = display.innerText + displayValue;
  })
);
```

Comment: You are not checking for presence of the `.` character anywhere, this may be the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to check for dot. What condition should i use? And i need something so user can't input multiple dots.

Comment: You're right, you do need to check for those conditions. Answer below should help you to check if the dot has been pressed, but I'm not going to write all your code for you

Comment: I think this will solve problem if user tries to input multiple dots.          if (display.innerText.includes(".") && displayValue == ".") {
      return;
    }

Comment: As a minor note, I would suggest renaming `displayValue` to `inputValue` for some increased clarity, but entirely up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler for a button press, simply add another condition for when the decimal is pressed:

```
buttons.forEach((btn) =>
    btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        displayValue = e.target.innerText;
        if (displayValue == "."){
            display.innerText = display.innerText + displayValue;
        }
        else if (display.innerText == "0") {
            display.innerText = displayValue;
        } else {
            display.innerText = display.innerText + displayValue;
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I couldn't figure this out in 4 days... Thank you.